# When a shaken soft-drink botte is left to calm down, does it return to the same state as before being shaken?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry, gas

We had a disagreement with a friend:

When a soft-drink (carbonated) bottle (e.g., 1.5l) is shaken or dropped on the floor, if opened immediately it will spill out. However, if it is left to "calm down", then it won't spill out. Does it, however, return to the same condition as before being shaken or dropped?

EDIT: To be clearer, I also want to know about the taste. Will the taste be the same before shaking and after shaking and "calming down"?

Comment: What is the disagreement?

Comment: One says the after-shaking equilibrium will be the same as the before-shaking one. The other says that after-shaking, the new-equlibrium will be different and the soft drink will not have the same taste (the drink will be "de-gassed").

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/comments/15vhr0i/when_a_shaken_softdrink_botte_is_left_to_calm/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it returns to the same condition. The carbon dioxide gas in the top of the bottle and the gas dissolved in the liquid were in equilibrium before the shaking, and the shaking releases some of the gas from the liquid, increasing the pressure in the gas part of the container. If it is left to calm down, this increased pressure in the gas part will make the carbon dioxide re-dissolve in the liquid until it reaches an equilibrium condition again, decreasing the pressure back to normal.

You can see this experimentally in the fact that the pressure in the bottle drops back to a normal one after some time, so when you open the bottle some minutes after a shock it doesn't spray out as it would do if the gas pressure increased due to a shock.

Comment: Your answer probably requires an edit.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux29SBmnZZ4